Linebreaks (CRLF) at beginning of line read from serial port via PySerial
I am trying to write commands and read responses to/from a serial port (RS232) on a laboratory pump. I have the pump connected to my PC via a USB-to-serial adaptor, and have been able to send commands fine but I'm struggling to read all lines of the pump's response.
I'm sending the command
    ser.write(b'ver\r\n') 

to which the pump should respond with its firmware version number, followed by a character representing its status (stopped (:), pumping (>), stalled(*)); I'm reading the response in PySerial with the following code:
    time.sleep(1)
    while True:
        line = ser.readline()
        print(line)

I'm monitoring the TX pin on the pump's port using an oscilloscope and using its automatic decoding feature; the scope shows this as the response:
CR LF SP SP 1 1 . 0 6 2 CR LF CR LF :

whereas my python script reads the response as
b'\r\n'
b'  11.062\r\n'
b'\r\n'

Clearly the colon at the end is not being read as it comes after the CR LF characters, and I believe that the pump is sending the EoL characters at the beginning of the line - i.e., what I should be reading is
b'\r\n  11.062'
b'\r\n'
b'\r\n:'

Is there a way to tell PySerial to look for EoL characters at the beginning lines, or to get it to continue reading the port even when no EoL characters are present?
I'm not particularly familiar with serial communication, so please forgive any naïvety.
See below for my full script:
import time
import serial

import traceback

print('Libraries imported')

# configure the serial connections
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM12',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
)

ser.isOpen()

try:
    print('Querying...')
    #\r is the CR (carriage return) character
    #\n is the LF (line feed) character
    #'b' makes it a bytearray (required type of serial.Serial.write() argument)
    ser.write(b'ver\r\n') 

    time.sleep(1)
    while True:
        line = ser.readline()
        print(line)

except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()

while True:
    entry = input("Press x to close terminal: ")
    if entry == 'x':
        break
    else:
        continue


Please read and understand the contents of the specification document carefully. As long as you are using the Readline method, \n is the delimiter data, and you cannot read it the way you want. You will need to analyze the data read by the read method yourself.

You probably only need to write \r to the serial port. Remember, your code is seen as a terminal, and terminals don't translate Enter to CRLF, it's just CR. So the \n is being treated as a second Enter.

Thank you @kunif I've replaced the use of readline() with a while loop that uses read() to access bytes one at a time, checking them to see if they are any of the characters that the pump uses to report its status, and breaking the loop if they are. All read bytes are added to a bytearray, from which the required characters are extracted.
